# Filter and load more wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, filter

I'm looking for a way to combine a filter script with the ability to load more posts (from custom post type).

The load more functionality works as expected, but I still have some problems with the filtering. I want to be able to filter on taxonomy, but the script that I started off with is working with `get_category();` and querying by `category_name`.

This is the query I've got right now:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
    function filter_projects() {
        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
          'post_type' => 'team',
          'posts_per_page' => 3,
          'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'category_name' =>  $_POST['category'],
        ]);
 
        $response = '';
      
        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            ob_start();
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) { 
                $ajaxposts->the_post();
                $response .= get_template_part('template-parts/team', 'member-listing');
            }
            $output = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        } else {
          $response = 'empty';
        }
        
        $result = [
            'html' => $output,
          ];
      
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
```

How do I edit this query for it to work with taxonomies?

For the full code in its current status:
Ajax: https://pastebin.com/iyqVQ5Se 
functions.php: https://pastebin.com/UTirBnUk 
Listing page: https://pastebin.com/XSWBni1f